# Why AndroidX element doesn't work? Element is not allowed here

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, androidx

I've made some changes to migrate my App to AndroidX manually because the Refactor tool doesn't work properly, following [this map file](https://gist.github.com/alexjlockwood/c59e74e95037f6c230dde8a39c328970). Amoung those changes I've updated Firebase imports in my `build.gradle` file. Everything works fine but this: there's a resource file that doesn't allow me to use `AndroidX` widgets. There are duplicates files like that all along my project, in one of them this change works, in the other doesn't. The other files, duplicate or not, work fine and the project is sync, build and launched right.

[image]

And the error file.

[image]

The error in all elements: Element `com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout` is not allowed here. I've alreay try to clean cache and reopen, and to remove .idea folder, still not working.

My questions: why are all those files duplicated? Why I can't use the widgets only in here?

**Edit:**
My .xml's have resources from AndroidX and Material

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spn_documento_evento"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            style="@style/SpinnerAppCompat"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <include layout="@layout/item_search"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp">
        <include layout="@layout/item_results_clear" />
        <include layout="@layout/item_filters_activated"  />
    </LinearLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_documentos" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/floating_new_document"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:alpha="0.7"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/floating_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/floating_audit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:alpha="0.7"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/floating_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_audit" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Where's the XML in question?? Besides, this is not AndroidX, but Material Design.

Comment: I'm not sure that the problem comes form the XML but I've edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Add following in `gradle.properties file`

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
```

And then rebuild the project

Comment: I've tried your solution but the problem remains, still not working

Comment: is there any problem in syncing?

Comment: Do you have material library in the gradle?

Comment: Yes, latest version: implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0"